# Comparing two folders for non identical files in CMD

Tags: file, comparison, cmd, directory

What I need to do is to compare two folders for non identical files in CMD with `DOS` commands.

When I find non identical files, I need to write them into a .txt file with full path so I can find out where these files are actually contained.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `comp` command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/comp

```
comp C:\PathA\A C:\PathB\B > C:\Comparison\comparison-between-A-B.txt
```

Comment: thanks but can you also show me how to write differences to a .txt file?

Comment: just redirect the output: `comp dir1 dir2 > output.txt`

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: Most console commands allow you to redirect their output using the standard syntax for redirection, e.g. `dir >D:\dir.txt` prints the output of `dir` to the `D:\dir.txt` file rather than to the screen. You could try the same with `comp`: `comp … >comp_results.txt`.

Comment: Link broken, now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/comp

Answer (score 4):

This is just another way to do it for those who might have problems with `comp` command..

With comp i had some problems so i found another solution by using :

```
dir D:\Projects\Comparison\YourFolder\ > D:\Projects\Comparison\filelist-you.txt
```

so this creates a filelist of folder than i did the same on my second folder which is gonna be compared..

```
dir D:\Projects\Comparison\MyFolder\ > D:\Projects\Comparison\filelist-me.txt
```

Than i compare them with this code:

```
fc D:\Projects\Comparison\filelist-you.txt D:\Projects\Comparison\filelist-me.txt
```

gives the true result..

Everything was fine till this step than i couldnt find out how to put these comparison results into a new .txt file..

Than i realized("with the help of @vulkanino") i already had the answer as `dir path1 > intopath2` so the solution is :

```
fc D:\Projects\Comparison\filelist-you.txt D:\Projects\Comparison\filelist-me.txt > D:\Projects\Comparison\filelist-comparison-between-you-me.txt
```

"`>`" is an output command that directs the output to the decided path.

Comment: In case you want to compare only filenames, use `DIR /B` instead of just `DIR`.

Comment: thanks for extended info i just put this answer for creating another point of view.

Answer (score 3):

If the directory you want to inventory includes files and other subdirectories then you must use the /S switch in order to "get" everything in your output.